# CursorAdapter with separators - how to get proper cursor?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to add separators between views using `CursorAdapter`.

I know how to add separators themselfs, but I'm not sure how to obtain suitable `Cursor` for 
such task. All data stored inside `CotentProvider` backed with SQLite database.

Separators stored as: `_id, name`

Items stored as: `_id, name, ... , separator_id`

**Solutions that I see so far**

1. Get all separators. For each separator independetly retrieve items. I think there will be a big overhead... or am I wrong?
2. Join tables on `item.separator_id = separator._id` and order result by some field of separator. Then, inside `CursorAdapter` look for changes of `separator_id` and insert separator view. Quite messy, I think.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its better so work with enum of separators. But in your case

```
public Cursor getItemList(){
     return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Items NATURAL JOIN Separators ON Item.separator_id = Separators._id");
    }
```

Create your custom CursorAdapter and manage it inside bindView method in your way.
Layout with view for separator should contain ImageView for separator inside.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
      LayoutInflater inflater;
      public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }
```

```
@Override
      public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //cursor is already setted to requared position, just get your column
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        tv2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)fimdViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
        if(cursor.getString(5) == "line"){
          myImageView = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/line.png");
        }else if(cursor.getString(5) == "wave"){
          myImageView = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/wave.png");
        ...
      }
```

```
  @Override
          public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            //here is view for each raws
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_raw_view, parent, false);
          }
        }
```